# jquery validator: custom conditional rule

Tags: jquery, validation, conditional-statements

I have an html select with first option value is "". I am validating it using a custom rule:

```
   $.validator.addMethod("requiredSelect", function (value, element, arg) {
      return arg != value;
   }, "Required field.");
```

and then doing:

```
dropdownField: {
   requiredSelect: ""
},
```

Now I need to make it conditional, so it is required only if a given checkbox is checked. If not using a custom rule I would be doing something like:

```
dropdownField: {
   required:'#myCheckbox:checked'
},
```

But how can I make my custom validator conditional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an `OR` operator (`||`) to the returned expression, so that you can also check the `checked` status of your checkbox:

```
$.validator.addMethod("requiredSelect", function (value, element, arg) {
  return !(arg !== value || $('#myCheckbox').is(':checked'));
}, "Required field.");
```

Your validator will return false when one or more of the conditions are truthy, in other words, when the checkbox is not checked, you will definitely flag the field as valid.

Comment: thanks! it almost worked with your code, just had to invert the result: return !( arg !== value || $('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')); and now its working as I need.

Comment: @patsy2k Ah, sorry that I misunderstood your question. Updated my answer :)